# How to use IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, disk

I'm trying to shrink my partition to the last used LCN. Has anybody used this control code?

I'm getting System Error code 87 every time in the following code:

```
HANDLE hDiskHandle = NULL;
        DISK_GROW_PARTITION dgp;
        DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;

        dgp.PartitionNumber = 2;
        dgp.BytesToGrow.QuadPart = -1;

        hDiskHandle = CreateFile(_T("\\.\PhysicalDrive0"), GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);
        if (hDiskHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            int err = GetLastError();
            printf("Unable to get handle on Volume, error : %d", err);
        }

        if (!DeviceIoControl(
                hDiskHandle,       
                IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION,  
                &dgp,
                sizeof dgp,      
                NULL,       
                0,     
                &dwBytesReturned,  
                NULL
                )) {
            int err = GetLastError();
            printf("DeviceIoControl Failed, error : %d", err);;
        }
```

My hard drive has 3 partitions (C, D, E). The E: drive is practically empty.

Comment: turns out my program was fine. After changing access from GENERIC_ALL to GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE it started working which i can't explain y... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OP's solution converted to answer below]

It turns out my program was fine.  It started working after changing access from

```
GENERIC_ALL
```

to

```
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
```